# Are products and coproducts truly dual?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

Coproducts can be defined similarly to products, reversing all the arrows. However just by doing this, we aren't really working in the opposite category, since the morphisms are still the ones in the original category. So it feels like coproducts are not really dual to products, since we aren't working in the opposite category.

Comment: By the very reason you gave, the co-product of $A,B\in \mathcal C$ is the product of $A,B\in C^{op}$

Comment: What makes you think you need the opposite category for something to be dual? First of all duality is not really a well defined mathematical concept. Secondly, you may want to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This makes me happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are dual, but your confusion stems from a very important distinction, and it's good that you thought about it.

A product in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a coproduct in the opposite category $\mathcal{C}^{op}$. You should check that using the universal properties! So they are dual, but only if you reverse all the arrows, i.e. pass to the opposite category.

If you just reverse the arrows in the definition, then you just get a different definition in the same category. In fact, there are categories in which products exist and coproducts do not, or vice versa.

A similar phenomenon is a classis source of confusion (and it was for me for a bit) when learning about projective and injective objects in abelian categories. Similarly, these are two dual notions, so when you know how to prove some property of projective objects, you automatically know the dual statement for injective objects, but when working in a fixed category, these 2 classes of objects tend to behave very differently.